# lastchild.appendchild in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, appendchild

The following code

```
var descriptdiv = document.createElement("div");
document.body.lastChild.appendChild(descriptdiv);
```

works in IE, but doesn't work in FireFox and Chrome. How can I get it to work in those browsers too?

Comment: The `lastChild` is not necessarily and Element node... you should check first... (or go with `lastElementChild` but that doesn't work in IE8)

Comment: No doubt the last child is a text node, possibly a line break that IE ignores. Put it in the last child that is an element that can contain a div-

Answer (score 1):

What you're most likely seeing is Firefox/Chrome returning text nodes as `lastChild`.  This is because these browsers will return any whitespace/newlines at the end of your code as text nodes.  Since you can't append a div to a text node, the code fails.

IE on the other hand will ignore the whitespace/newlines and return the last element, which you can successfully append to. You can use a function like [the following](http://www.w3schools.com/Dom/prop_document_lastchild.asp) to get the last element:

```
function getLastChild(n) {    
    var x = n.lastChild;

    // noteType == 1 is an element node - keep searching until we find one
    while (x && x.nodeType != 1){
      x = x.previousSibling;
    }

    // don't allow a non element node to be returned.
    if(x && x.nodeType != 1){
      x = null;
    }
    return x;    
}
```

Comment: Not only that, but the code will crash if the element is empty, or doesn't contain any element nodes. Don't use code from W3Schools.

Comment: Ew...you're right - that's some bad copy/paste on my part.  Fixed up the code.

Comment: Yes, junk from w3schools. The code in the second if test will never be run because from the first test, x must be *null* or nodeType 1.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add a block element to an img, br, hr  and many others, 
and there are some you can that you won't ever need to.

You probably have some idea of the container you want.

```
function addaBlocktothelastChild(block, rx){
    var next, elements= document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'),
    L= elements.length, count= L;
    rx= rx ||  /^(DIV|P|TD|LI|DT|DD)$/i;
    while(L && !rx.test(elements[--L].tagName));
    if(L>= 0){
        return elements[L].appendChild(block);
    }
    return document.body.appendChild(block);
}



var block= document.createElement('div');
block.id= 'Zed';
addaBlocktothelastChild(block);
alert(document.getElementById('Zed').parentNode)
```

**/^(DIV|P|TD|LI|DT|DD|BLOCKQUOTE|FORM|ARTICLE|ASIDE|FOOTER|HEADER|NAV|SECTION)/i**